# Idiomatic AmE term for "B&B"/"bed & breakfast"/"chambre d'hôte" and "table d'hôte"

Tags: american-english, vocabulary, word-usage

Is there an idiomatic term or expression in modern day AmE for what in the UK is designated by the shared "B&B"/"bed & breakfast", and seemingly by the originally FrF expression "chambre d'hote" [an accommodation offered by an inn, hotel, or especially a private home, consisting of a room for the night, and breakfast for the next morning at an inclusive price, but also the hostelry itself]?

Also, what do you Americans call what in FrF is referred to as "table d'hôte"?

Comment: Yes, Americans call it a *"bed & breakfast"*, especially if it's a private home or a small hotel.

Comment: _table d'hôte_ is used in English, in two senses. Originally in the sense of what I now hear being called the _chef's table_, and more often nowadays as _set price menu_ or _fixed menu_.

Comment: @PeterShor what is a hostelry compared with a B&B?

Comment: Are there any American establishments that call themselves *"hostelries"* today? I thought that word was archaic. (I can find ones in the U.K.—where they seem to be playing up the antiquity of the establishment—and in Asia, where they presumably don't realize it's an archaic word.)

Comment: @PeterShor If I asked you this question, Peter, it's just because "hostelry" is defined as an Americanism in some of my bilingual dictionaries out here. And so, I thought Americans were likely to use that term when they travel abroad to refer to some historical quaint hotel or guesthouse or inn.

Comment: [Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=hostelry%3Aeng_gb_2012%2Chostelry%3Aeng_us_2012&year_start=1700&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chostelry%3Aeng_gb_2012%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chostelry%3Aeng_us_2012%3B%2Cc0) shows *"hostelry"* to have been mainly used between 1850 and 1950 in both the U.K. and the U.S. My estimate of when it was current was off by a century or two, but my impression is that it is outdated today.

Comment: Compare hostelry to youth hostel.  Which to my ear is the only currency of the term in AmE.  We also don't use the term pension in the same way as in Europe.  We would use the term guest house, but it carries the notion of being an inexpensive long-term residence, not a pension hotel.

Comment: @DavidM Check out this L.A. Times article, David. Second line in the second paragraph http://articles.latimes.com/2009/dec/05/local/la-me-hotel5-2009dec05

Comment: @NourishedGourmet It's a ... literary license?  It's a term that Americans will understand in print, but will never say unless they are trying to be *fancy*.  Upscale hostelry ...

Comment: @DavidM We don't use the French equivalent "hostellerie" either. It kind of sounds archaic in modern day French also, and is mostly found by the name of elegant countryside style hotels and inns, presumably for marketing reasons as it gives a true rural, traditional, and cozy feel to them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

B&B or Bed & Breakfast are rather common terms.

They are typically a room in a residence or former residence turned small hotel.  The proprietor is typically the owner. And, as the name suggests you get a bed and breakfast for the price.

In AmE, B&Bs are typically very quaint places found in rustic locations.  If you look rather hard,  can find a Bed & Breakfast in a major city, but major hotel chains tend to dominate there.  But, because of the identity with rustic locales, it carries the notion of a "romantic getaway".

You would typically not bring children or family to a B&B.

A small hotel with inexpensive rooms of varying quality is known as a *motel*. A portmanteau of motor and hotel.  The notion is a hotel for motorists which requires no reservations.  You would bring children or families to a motel.

Motels have a wide variation in quality from "seedy" (meaning a place to pick-up prostitutes and hide out from the police) to polished, clean, but inexpensive national chains.

The two French terms you mentioned have no currency in AmE. *Table d'hôte* has largely been replaced by terms like *Chef's table* for the original sense of a "host's table".  Or *prix fixe* menu in the more modern sense.

Comment: I have to disagree with you on one point: there are bed and breakfasts in most major cities. You do have to make an effort to look for them, as large hotels are quite a bit more common, have a lot more beds, and are easier to find on the internet. (But not much of an effort … Googling "bed and breakfast" with the city name typically finds them.)

Comment: @PeterShor I guess you are right. I'll edit to reflect that.

Comment: @DavidM David, I can't seem to latch onto what is meant by "vacation" herein http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Table_d'hôte

Comment: @NourishedGourmet I'll be honest. Neither can I. Wikipedia is edited by the crowd, sometimes oddities slip through. If you, a Frenchman, don't understand the context, it's likely invalid.

Comment: I would absolutely bring children to a Bed and Breakfast in North America.

Comment: @DJClayworth would you?  I generally wouldn't. They're not usually equipped with anything but a single queen or king-sized bed.